# convert_uuencode a php file

Tags: php, uudecode

I want to encode a php file with uuencode to use it with

```
eval(gzuncompress(convert_uudecode("somedata");
```

I only found a way to encode a string, but no way to encode a complete php file (or php code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read data of your file

`$contentString = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_PHP/some.php)`

adn then do same `eval(gzuncompress(convert_uudecode($contentString)));`

**UPDATE**

if you need to have as result this string

`<?php eval(gzuncompress(convert_uudecode("M>)S=6PEOVTBR_BL90,\x5c2(9D0;W+\x5c%.Q@UKL;O,7,K. ............. a")));`

you have to do following

```
// Reading file content
$phpFileContent = file_get_content("PATH/some.php");

// Remove <?php and ?> from your content
$phpFileContent = str_replace(array('<?php', '?>'), '', $phpFileContent);

// Encoding and compressing
$phpFileContent = convert_uuencode(  gzcompress($phpFileContent) );

// Your result string
$result = '<?php eval(gzuncompress(convert_uudecode("' . $phpFileContent . '")));';

//which you can write to some other php file with file_put_contensts
file_put_contents ( 'PATH_TO_RESULT_FILE/result.php' , $result);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, thats what I need. Do I have to gzcompress and uuencode the string? I nneda output like here: http://pastebin.com/VXGPaByw

Comment: Yes, if your `some.php` file contain encoded data then you have to decode it through appropriate way `convert_uudecode` and `gzuncompress` then only pass it to `eval`. `file_get_contents` is just returns you content of given path file without any decodeing

Comment: OK, but how can I encode the data first? I need a output like in the sample link on top, e.g. `M>)S=6PEOVTBR_BL90,\x5c2(9D0;W+\x5c%.Q@UKL;O,7,K.-98!\x24`...

I tried with `file_get_contents` and `convert_uuencode` but that gave me a wrong output.

Comment: check text under above *UPDATE*

Comment: Great Armen, it works like a charme.

You are gorgeous.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Read the file first

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Encode the content and then do whatever you want with it.